# Angularjs : failing to generate c3 directive based charts dynamically

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, c3.js, angularjs-compile

I am trying to create c3 charts dynamically using c3 chart directives. C3 chart directive is working fine. However dynamic chart creation upon button click is not working. Can any one suggest where I am going wrong?
Please find my plunker at http://plnkr.co/edit/wWJx3zU3Sm1cN9ZCtvoh?p=preview

I am compiling my c3 directive as shown below:

```
 $scope[chartName] = {

    data: {
        x: 'x',
        columns: [["x","2014-02-01","2014-03-01","2014-04-01","2014-05-01","2014-06-01","2014-07-01","2014-08-01","2014-09-01"],["LH",".00",".00",".00",".00",".00",".00",".00","31.50"],["DW","42.57",".00",".00","321.14","1070.06","6501.42","144337.85","329159.85"],["PS",".00","82.22","-2.87","179.60","835.85","6925.52","479631.24","1386751.16"]],
        type: 'line'
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: "timeseries",
            tick: {
                format: "%d-%m-%Y"
            }
        }
    },
    subchart: {
        show: true
    }

};

   var  template = ' <div class="col"> <p class="graphtitle">' + dashletterName + ' </p> <c3-simple id = "' + chartName + '" config="' + chartName + '"></c3-simple> </div>';
     angular.element(document.body).append($compile(template)($scope));
```

Comment: I am trying to something like shown in http://plnkr.co/edit/0XtT0f?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded you Plnkr and tried it in browser. Here is error from Chrome console:

```
ReferenceError: $compile is not defined
```

This means that AngularJS can't use $compile, because it is not injected into your controller. This should be done in *controllers.js* like this:

```
// I have added $compile
controller('DemoCtrl', ['$scope', 'c3SimpleService', '$compile', function ($scope, c3SimpleService, $compile)
{
  // rest of the controller code
}
```

I also fixed your [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/wiiUMk2KoHHrK4D1HdNu?p=preview). Hope it helps :)

Comment: Is there any simple way to set the sub chart back ground color  in easy way using c3 directives. Please find my post on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30665391/custom-attribute-type-directive-to-set-the-background-color-of-c3-chart